# How to put the ByteArrayInputStream content into a PDF using iText?

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext, bytearrayoutputstream

I have the following situation, into a method I have:

```
ByteArrayInputStream fis = new ByteArrayInputStream(Bean.getValoreString("PDFmulti", "PDF").getBytes());
```

As you can see **fis** varialbe is a **ByteArrayInputStream** and **Bean.getValoreString("PDFmulti", "PDF").getBytes()** returns a  **byte[]**

So now I need to put the content of the **fis** object into a PDF using iText.

What can I do to do it? I think that I have to read this input stream and put its content into a **ByteArrayOutputStream**, something like this:

```
public static byte[] readFully(InputStream stream) throws IOException
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = stream.read(buffer)) != -1)
    {
        baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

But then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment to your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28342714/how-to-convert-a-string-object-representing-a-pdf-into-a-bytearrayinputstream-th, you say *I have to concatenate all the PDF to create a single PDF.*

This is crucial information that you are omitting in your new question. If I read your new question, it's as if you want to persist a PDF that exists in a `byte[]` in some other form. For instance: you want to store it as a file.

If that is the case, then you don't need iText! Just write the bytes to a `FileOutputStream`!

However, now that I know that you need to concatenate files, I know that you need several `PdfReader` instances and then use these `PdfReader` instances in combination with `PdfCopy` (or `PdfSmartCopy`) to create a single PDF out of a series of different PDFs.

That's a completely different question! In that case, why would you create a `ByteArrayOutputStream`? There is a [`PdfReader` contructor](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.html#PdfReader(java.io.InputStream)) that accepts an `InputStream` as a parameter. Why not pass `fis` to that constructor?